# The Elm way of transforming flags to model

Tags: elm

I have the following types in my app:

```
type Page
    = Welcome
    | Cards


type alias Flags =
    { recipientName : String
    , products : List Product
    }


type alias Product =
    { id : Int
    , name : String
    , price : Float
    , liked : Maybe Bool
    }


type alias Model =
    { recipientName : String
    , currentPage : Page
    , products : List Product
    }
```

I am passing an array of products as flags. Here's what my `init` looks like:

```
init : Flags -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags =
    let
        { recipientName, products } =
            flags
    in
        Model recipientName Welcome products
            |> withNoCmd
```

The challenge I'm facing is that the products in this array only have `id`, `name`, and `price` attributes. So, given the `Flags` definition, every time I extend `Product` with a new attribute (such as `liked`), the array of products passed as flags will need to have that attribute as well. For now, I just render them as empty, but this doesn't feel right, so I was wondering what is the Elm way™ of receiving flags and transforming them into the model? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your `Product` is already defined as an input (or the environment) of your app:

```
type alias Product =
    { id : Int
    , name : String
    , price : Float
    }
```

and you are augmenting this with info that relates the Recipient to the Products. I'd suggest splitting this out into its own type that can grow as your app grows, eg:

```
type alias Opinion =
    { liked : Maybe Bool
    , review : String
    , preferredColor : Color
    }
```

then you can tie these together in your `Model`:

```
type alias Model =
    { recipientName : String
    , currentPage : Page
    , products : List (Product, Opinion)
    }
```

or, depending on how the application works, you might end up wanting to look up the recipient's opinion by `product.id`:

```
    ...
    , products : List Product
    , opinions : Dict Int Opinion
```

The point is that if you keep the original `Product` unchanged, you can build a small library of functions that work on `Product`, both for inventory (where no recipient is involved) and for the customer. Maybe you can re-use the `Opinion` type for customer metrics.

If these two types are likely to evolve, keeping them separate can help ensure you don't end up with messy and bug-attracting interdependencies.